# cannot access Task class file for com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task not found

Tags: android

Okay so I have a problem as the title. It says

> Error:(69, 27) error: cannot access Task class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task not found

and i don't know what that means and how to solve it. I was searching for it almost for the day and nothing helped me.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'key'
            keyPassword 'pass'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/Alan/Nameless_release_key.jks')
            storePassword 'pass'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sstudio.nameless"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and here is my gradle console output

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
The getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method instead.
The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead.
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareAndroidArchCoreRuntime100Alpha8Library
:app:prepareAndroidArchLifecycleExtensions100Alpha8Library
:app:prepareAndroidArchLifecycleRuntime100Alpha8Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2602Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72602Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72602Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2602Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2602Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2602Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2602Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2602Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42602Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2602Library
:app:prepareComFirebaseuiFirebaseUiDatabase230Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection1104Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1001Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\New folder\Nameless\app\google-services.json
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\New folder\Nameless\app\src\main\java\com\sstudio\nameless\ChatActivity.java:69: error: cannot access Task
        me.push().setValue("online");
                          ^
  class file for com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task not found
1 error

 FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s

38 actionable tasks: 33 executed, 5 up-to-date
```

help me out here. If you need any more information i will update it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your response. The problem is now gone. **Updating every dependency** and platform plugins to its **latest version** solved it. To all of you out there, never... never ignore an **update**. unless you want to bang and bleed your head.

Comment: I'm sorry but cleaning the project after the update did solve the problem for me. I cannot explain how exactly it did work, as I, myself don't understand the problem that well. sorry and good luck.